# How to enable PHP native sessions in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to integrate Facebook's API in a CodeIgniter project, however it seems to be not working because sessions are disabled somehow in CodeIgniter. (Trying to integrate outside CodeIgniter works, but inside a codeigniter project it doesn't work).

Is there any way to do this? All I want is for native sessions to not be cleared or destroyed by CodeIgniter. If the only way is to hack the core to remove a line or two, then I'm willing to do it. I think there's someplace where its doing `$_SESSION = null` or something like that. Where's this place, so I can remove that line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow this blog on a fresh CI install, it works without any problem:

http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/

From there, you can continue to build you application, or find where it goes wrong.

Comment: Right, it looks like facebook's SDK uses `$_REQUEST` instead of GET, from that blog I got that it needs to use GET, i did a replace of that and now its working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a library to extend CI sessions (which are cookies) to use native server sessions.

Have a look at this [native session](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session) library.

Answer (score 0):

in CI session are not disabled.
It must be done in your manual coding.
Please refer your coding again.

It is also possible that some jQuery - JS is conflicted in project, which can destroy session.